# Trace of a matrix using property

Tags: matrices

If

${P_1} = I = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{array}} \right];{P_2} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&0&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&1&0
\end{array}} \right];{P_3} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&1&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{array}} \right];{P_4} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
1&0&0
\end{array}} \right];{P_5} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&0&1\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&0
\end{array}} \right];{P_6} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
1&0&0
\end{array}} \right]$

and

$X = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^6 {{P_i}\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
2&1&3\\
1&0&2\\
3&2&1
\end{array}} \right]{P_i}^T} $

where $P_k^T$ denotes the transpose of the matrix $P_k$. Then which of the following options is are correct ?

(A) $X\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{array}} \right] = \alpha \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{array}} \right]$, then $\alpha =30$

(B) X is symmetric Matrix

(C) The sum of diagonal entries of X is 18

(D) $X-30I$ is an invertible matrix

The official answer is A,B,C . I have solved the option A,B and D and have proved that A&B are correct and D is incorrect.

For Choice C I need some help

$X = {P_1}Q{P_1}^T + {P_2}Q{P_2}^T + {P_3}Q{P_3}^T + {P_4}Q{P_4}^T + {P_5}Q{P_5}^T + {P_6}Q{P_6}^T$

${P_1} = I = {P_1}^T$

$X = \underbrace Q_{Traace = 3} + {P_2}Q{P_2}^T + {P_3}Q{P_3}^T + {P_4}Q{P_4}^T + {P_5}Q{P_5}^T + {P_6}Q{P_6}^T$

In most of the solution they only solved $Trace(P_1QP_1^T)=3$ and they multipled by 6 to get the answer 18. How do we solve it using property.

Comment: Are you asking C or A? if it is C then recall that $$\operatorname{tr}(ABC) = \operatorname{tr}(CAB) = \operatorname{tr}(BCA)$$ and the fact that the Type-1 elementary matrix has transpose equal to its inverse, therefore $P_iP_i^T = I$.

Comment: Yes for choice C I have modified it

Comment: saw that. I think the hints are enough for you to solve.

Comment: @macton I agree most of the solution I found uses the above concept but I need to solve it via some concept

Comment: While I don't see why you don't use the above concept, a "brute-force" method is to claim that the diagonal elements of $A$ will still be in the diagonal after left-multiply by $T_i$ and right-multiply by $T_i^T$ for all $i$.Then the trace are all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each given $P_i$, pairwise dot product of column vectors (or row vectors) is zero and magnitude of each column (or row) vector is $1$. Thus each $P_i$ is orthogonal matrix.

$$P_iP_i^{T}=I$$

Using the hint given by @macton in comments,

$$\text{Tr}(P_iQP_i^{T})=\text{Tr}(QP_iP_i^{T})=\text{Tr}(Q) $$
$$\therefore \text{Tr}(X)=6 \, \text{Tr}(Q)=18$$